# How to format Laravel Blade files consistently across VS Code and PhpStorm (and other IDEs if possible)?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade, prettier

Our time is getting bigger and bigger, and we we need to have consistent code formatting in our repos. Some devs are using VS Code, some are using PhpStorm.

Now there is already a popular extension https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html and it works on most popular IDEs out there. The problem we are facing it, it still doesn't format Blade files from Laravel. Is there a way we can tell Prettier to do that? Will it work for both VS Code and PhpStorm, and other IDEs?

What do other people do to over come this problem? Multiple devs using different IDEs and still same formatting rules somehow so that git is not noisy and overwhelming?

UPDATE:

I found a npm package called `blade-formater` which I installed using `npm install -g blade-formatter` this command and I can run something like `blade-formatter -w "resources/views/**/*.blade.php"` to format all blade views.

Now to make it work across IDEs, I am thinking I can somehow call it when blade files are changed, and a watcher detects it and calls this command. I have Laravel Mix, so I think it should be possible but I am not sure how. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For php prettier is not good. https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: https://dev.to/ibrarturi/setup-php-cs-fixer-for-laravel-project-44nf Tried this guide, but even the default config tells fixer to ignore blade files, does that mean it doesn't work for balde files or just excuded as an option? @Maksim

Comment: https://gist.github.com/laravel-shift/cab527923ed2a109dda047b97d53c200

same with this, ignoring blade files :(